# How to convert nested NOT EXISTS query to LINQ

Tags: linq, t-sql

Any idea how to convert this to linq?

```
SELECT DISTINCT PartNumber AS [PartNumber That Includes EVERY ItemNumber Listed in @RequiredItemsTable]
  FROM Part.BillsOfMaterialsFlattened AS bom1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT *
          FROM @RequiredItemsTable w
         WHERE NOT EXISTS
               (SELECT *
                  FROM Part.BillsOfMaterialsFlattened AS bom2
                 WHERE (bom1.PartNumber = bom2.PartNumber)
                   AND (bom2.ItemNumber = w.ItemNumber)));
```

I've seen several examples on this site, tried to emulate them....but so far not getting there.

thanks!

Here's a tabular example of what I'm seeking to achieve via linq.  The foregoing T-SQL does the trick.

```
Part.BillsOfMaterialsFlattened
PartNumber  ItemNumber
10041047    10034480
10041047    10041090
10041047    10041091
10041048    10034480
10041048    10041091
10041049    10034650
10041049    10041090
10041049    10041091
10041050    10034650
10041050    10041091
10041061    10001331
10041061    10001422

@RequiredItemsTable
ItemNumber
10041090
10041091
```

Want LINQ statement to generate `IQueryable<String>`

```
PartNumber (Part Numbers that include all Required Item Numbers)
10041047
10041049
```

Comment: Attempted to follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899090/linq-where-not-exists

Comment: I attempted to follow the technique outlined in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899090/linq-where-not-exists with this code...well I have so many lines commented out I'm not sure which set exactly emulates that technique.  I also took a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114342/convert-this-sql-query-to-linq-not-exists-sub-query and I'm interested in it's technique of restructuring the code into sargable predicates.  I had never previously heard of the term "sargable" (I have a mechanical engineering background).  I'd like an extremely efficient linq query.

Comment: The restrictions on this site seem weird to me.  God forbid that you should get up in the middle of writing a comment to take a leak. Seriously, 5 minutes max to edit your comment.  Lastly, I was trying to follow Joe Celko's Division with Remainder technique posted here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following linq does the trick:

```
var requiredItems = criteria.BomItemsIncluded.AsQueryable();
var partNumbers = (from b in _db.BillsOfMaterialsFlatteneds
                    group b by b.PartNumber into g
                    where requiredItems.All(r => g.Select(_ => _.ItemNumber).Contains(r))
                    select g.Key).Distinct();
```